# How to prevent ActionBar SearchView button from disappearing

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview, android-optionsmenu

I have been having a lot of trouble trying to fix this one and couldn't find any solutions for this anywhere.

Currently I have the following ActionBar option menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="@string/menu_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_sort_by"
        android:title="@string/sort_by"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:title="@string/action_refresh"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

And everything works perfectly fine except if the options menu is opened while the search option is also opened:

The target layout as expected

[image]

The search option opened

[image]

This is the step that causes the problem, as you can see the Search option is now in the menu

[image]

Because of the previous step the search button is gone when closing the menu and the search option

[image]

If I don't open the options menu while the search option is also opened then everything works perfectly well, however this is something that cannot be expected for users to do and they might open the menu with the search options opened, leading to the search icon to disappear, resulting in a very problematic user experience.

How can I fix this, how can I prevent this problem from happening while keeping that same layout? Search icon visible, everything else in the 3 dots options menu.

Comment: your problem is when both of them (search and options menu) are opening, aren't they?

Comment: @propoLis No, I opened the options menu manually after opening the search option. This is the step that causes the problem, if I don't open that menu while the search is opened then the search icon does not disappear afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To always show the search icon, simple change `app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"` to `app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"`

Comment: Oh shoot, shoot, shoot! No way! The reason as to why I have never went with this option is because Android always warns "Prefer ifRoom instead of always" and links here https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html

Comment: Can only accept answer after 5 minutes, I'll have to wait a bit, but this is the answer to my problem!